# How to add colors with a pipe?

Tags: zsh

I want to pipe the output of a command to something able to color the occurrences of a specific word.

Example: **echo "ABC DEF GHI" | *magic_color_thing("DEF")*** should print out **ABC DEF GHI** with **DEF** colored.

I want to do it with ZSH and I want to preserve all the lines as well as the carriage returns.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
echo "...... DEF....." | grep --color "DEF"
```

do the job for you?

It would help if you said more about the kind of data you were piping in.

(And also whether lines without matches are important or not)

Comment: Thank you, but grep will output only the matching lines (I edited the question to be more precise).
The input is the output of another command, it can be `echo`, `cat`, or anything else.

Comment: In that case, I seem to remember a little app called 'supercat' http://supercat.nosredna.net/ poorly documented, as in, you have to read the config files to understand it, but it should do what you ask. The alternative is to use sed or awk to insert the ANSI colour codes around the text you wish to highlight.

Comment: Probably unfair to leave you with a throwaway mention of 'just use 'sed' ->  $ echo "....... foo... " | sed 's/foo/ESC[33mfooESC[0m/g'     (where ESC is char code 27: press Ctrl-V then press the Escape key.) See  http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html for a list of colours.

Comment: You can use `$'\e'` for escape and `$'\C-c'` for <C-smth> instead of embedding raw control codes.

Comment: Better, you can use `autoload colors && colors`, then `... | sed $'s/foo/\e['$color[red]$'mfoo\e['$color[none]$'m/g'` to avoid magic numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you have (a recent version of) GNU grep, use its `--color` option. To have it print non-matching lines as well, use a pattern that matches the empty string.

```
… | grep --color -E '|DEF'
```

If you want to do it entirely within zsh, make it iterate over the lines, surrounding `DEF` with color codes.

```
autoload colors; colors
while IFS= read -r line; do
  print -r -- "${line//DEF/$fg[red]DEF$fg[default]}"
done
```

See also [How to have tail -f show colored output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8414/885), and a few other [questions tagged `color`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/colors).